# React Redux initState

Tags: javascript, react, redux

É comum quando você trabalha com *redux* definir um state inicial, exemplo:

```
const initState = {
    pagInicial:1,
    pagAtual:1,
    maxLinks:2,
    maxReg:5
}
```

Até ai tudo bem. Agora e quando eu preciso de um state inicial, iniciando com alguns parâmetros e campos calculados, exemplo:

```
const initState = {
    pagInicial:1,
    totReg:pegar total registros
    pagAtual:1,
    maxLinks:2,
    maxReg:5,    
    totLinks:Math.ceil(totReg/maxReg),
    regInit:((maxReg*pagAtual​)-maxReg),
    regFim:(maxReg*pagAtual​))
}
```

*totReg*, *TotLinks*, *regInit*, *regFim*, **como informar no *Redux* o state incial destes campos?**

Answer (score 2):

O estado Redux do aplicativo ("estado do aplicativo") armazena informações necessárias para o uso do aplicativo. O estado inicial é determinado para conveniência e pra detalhar quais as propriedades que serão usadas pelo aplicativo. Normalmente, usamos valores iniciais como string vazia, null, lista vazia, etc para indicar que os dados ainda não foram obtidos.

Não se recomenda armazenar valores computados no estado do aplicativo se aquele valor for obtido por uma operação nos dados que já estiverem armazenados no estado.

Você já tem acesso aos dados via o Redux, então faça os cálculos no próprio componente usando as propriedades existentes. Você pode fazer isso também no mapStateToProps.

Answer (score 0):

Complementando o que o amigo @nbkhope respondeu, você pode criar os estados com  valores default e utilizar a função **[ComponentWillMount()](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)** para setar os states com os valores desejados.

[> The componentWillMount() is a chance for us to handle configuration, update our state, and in general prepare for the first render.](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/birth/premounting_with_componentwillmount.html)